# Getting error due to clearing all the characters in search textField when using Regex for search in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a **textField** & when I type on it a **tableView** appear below and show the search results. Thats all fine, I tried to highlight the search text character by character and its working as well. When I press cross button and clear all the text on the **textField** it crushes. Here is my code below:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style:.subtitle, reuseIdentifier:"searchCell")

    let predictions = myPredictions[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.attributedText = boldSearchResult(searchString: self.startTxtField.text!, resultString: predictions.attributedPrimaryText.string)

    return cell

}
```

and here is the function for character highlighting:

```
  func boldSearchResult(searchString: String, resultString: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {

    let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: resultString)
    let pattern = NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: searchString.lowercased())
    let range: NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, resultString.count)

    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpression.Options())

    regex.enumerateMatches(in: resultString.lowercased(), options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(), range: range) { (textCheckingResult, matchingFlags, stop) -> Void in
        let subRange = textCheckingResult?.range
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0), range: subRange!)
    }

    return attributedString

}
```

When I clear all the text it crashes there coz it find the **searchString** empty and it crushes. I don't know how to catch the exception.

Comment: It sounds like you need to skip the call to `boldSearchResult` if the text of the field `isEmpty`.

Comment: Yes I understand, but suppose **textField** is empty at the beginning, when typing its not empty, when I clear the text again it become empty agin. How can I detect this on the fly ?

Comment: You must already be doing that if the highlighting is working.